# Script To find installed software

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

We are planning to write a script which will get all the software installed in the Windows system and compare with the list which we have listed and send the result by mail.

I tried a lot and got the below script. The issue is it wont get all the programs installed in the system. Most of the software are missing and also compare is not working. Please help me to improve my script.

```dos
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (D:\BatchScript\ListeProgs.txt) do echo %%i >>D:\BatchScript\newfile.txt
@echo off > D:\BatchScript\installed-programs.csv
regedit /e D:\BatchScript\regexport.txt "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MicrosoftWindows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
find "DisplayName" < D:\BatchScript\regexport.txt > D:\BatchScript\regprogs.txt
for /f "tokens=enter code here2 delims==" %%a in (D:\BatchScript\regprogs.txt) do (
echo %%~a >>D:\BatchScript\installedprogs.txt )
for /f "tokens=*" %%L in (D:\BatchScript\installedprogs.txt) do (
call :sub1 %%L )
goto :eof
:sub1
>> installed-programs.csv echo %1,%2,%3,%4,%5,%6,%7,%8,%9
::== DONE
```

Comment: I did it with powershell a while ago. Let me find the script

Comment: another way to get installed software: `wmic product get caption` (also not complete, but maybe it helps to fill some gaps)

Comment: @user2693302 is powershell OK?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the script that will solve your problem.

After running this code in Powershell you will get a function named `Get-InstalledAppsDifferences`:

```sh
function Get-InstalledAppsDifferences {
    Process {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique > c:\LatestList.txt
        IF (Test-Path C:\PreviousList.txt)
        {
            Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content C:\latestList.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content C:\PreviousList.txt) > "C:\Diff_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
            Remove-Item C:\PreviousList.txt -Force
        }
        Move-Item C:\LatestList.txt C:\PreviousList.txt
    }
}
```

To run the function inside powershell:

```
Get-InstalledAppsDifferences
```

The function generates a list of currently installed programs in `C:\LatestList.txt` then  looks for a file named `C:\PreviousList.txt`, if found generates differences and saves into a file name `C:\Diff_yyyy-mm-dd.txt` and removes  the previous list.

At the end it renames `LatestList.txt` to `PreviousList.txt` for the next use.

Comment: But it's possible that software may be installed that isn't returned by Win32_Product, isn't it?

Comment: I never encountered such a problem, but if you have a special case or documentation stating this, I will appreciate it :)

Comment: It only enumerates software installed by MSI, and [apparently is very slow](http://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/)

Comment: You are right. It is very slow. But for a script that runs once in a day, who cares about 60 more seconds?

Comment: This approach is dangerous.  Querying Win32_Product is not a read-only operation.  This initiates a consistency check of packages, which can lead to attempts to repair installations.  Additionally, the query is incredibly slow.  Some of this is covered [this Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software.aspx) post